# Movies uploaded to iTunes

Tags: itunes

How do I get the movies that I have uploaded to iTunes from my Mac to show up on my iPad? I have several movies that I would like to see on my iPad. I figured the best way to upload to iTunes, but when I launch iTunes on my iPad I cannot see or find them.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=copy+a+movie+to+ipad

Comment: Note that the iTunes app on your iPad is only the iTunes Music Store, nothing more. You have to transfer the movie to your iPad using the iTunes app on your Mac.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105377/import-movies-already-on-computer-into-itunes and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49379/how-to-transfer-itunes-videos-to-ipad

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any such thing as "uploading" to iTunes on the Mac. Rather, you import/add your own video files to your library or purchase them from the iTunes store.

Any movie or tv show purchased from the iTunes store should automatically be in your Mac iTunes library and also be able play on your iPad after you sync it there.

You can import pretty much any movie file of your own to your Mac iTunes library. From there, you can use iTunes to sync it to your iPad; however, your iPad can only play a few specific movie formats ([scroll down to TV and Video](https://www.apple.com/ipad-air-2/specs/)). If your movies aren't in that format, you won't be able to play them on the iPad whether you sync them or not.

Once your iPad is connected to your Mac, you have options in iTunes on the Mac to auto-sync certain playlists of videos or all videos to your iPad. You can also use it manually, and simply drag/drop the desired video files from your Mac iTunes library onto your iPad library when it is connected to iTunes.